# What happening with Math.sin and Math.cos in Java? And how fix it?

Tags: java, math, graphics, trigonometry

I'm trying to implement [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). But a have a very strange effect:
[image: How it look like]

This is my code:

```
public void rotation(PointF point, double a) {

    point.x = (point.x - 400) * Math.cos(a) - (point.y - 300) * Math.sin(a)
            + 400;
    point.y = (point.x - 400) * Math.sin(a) + (point.y - 300) * Math.cos(a)
            + 300;
}
```

In result a have a falling point in coordinates 400,300.

What is wrong? I want point to move by circle? How I can do better?

Comment: What happens if you change `400` to `400f` and `300` to `300f`

Comment: Nothing. Is still "falling". My point.x is a double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well shouldn't it be like

```
double x = point.x * Math.cos(a) - point.y * Math.sin(a);
double y = point.x * Math.sin(a) + point.y * Math.cos(a);
point.x = x;
point.y = y;
```

to prevent modifying point.x too early?